# Listening to music in the background

Tags: dropbox, music

In my Samsung with Android, when I open an MP3 file from the Dropbox folder, I hear the music, but when I go to another application, the music stops.

Is there a way to listen to the music in the background, while I do other things?

Comment: When I click the MP3 file, I am asked whether I want to use "Google Play" or "Sound Player". I guess the preinstalled app is the "Sound Player". Anyway, whether I choose this or that option, the sound is only played in the foreground, and stops when I switch to another app.

Comment: Try looking for the settings which allow the player to keep playing in the background. I'm not sure which player you are using so i don't know if and where this setting will be, but most players have them these days.

Comment: @Andruseto the samsung is sm-t330nu.

Comment: ...and i do not know how to find my android version.

Comment: ah, i see, it is android 4.4.2

Answer (score 1):

Go to the pop up menu for the file and select export, Then save it to the device. Now it's on your phone and can be played via your native media player

Answer (score -2):

Download Google Play Music if it already isn't installed. It always works...